# Mobile app SDK : where to look? what to choose?

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, surface

I'm a software engineer looking for a multi mobile platform SDK (Surface Pro, Surface RT, iOS) to develop an application for merchant navy.

To make things short:

- the mariners are application users and will carry a device all day long (12h) on their vessel in order to fill their daily check list.
- The check list is uploaded to application on the mobile device at start of day.
- To get this daily check list, the end user will connect the mobile device to onboard computer (USB,Wifi,Bluetooth?)
- When the day is done, the end user will connect back to onboard computer and start pushing back the user data to a local database or storage.

Any tips would be appreciated on what mobile technology and SDK I should start on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at MS visual studio - create a hybrid mobile -HTML5 / JS  (AngularJS) along with WINJS to target mulitple devices

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll check on the hybrid mobile app SDK on VS.